# Own function for copying directories and files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write my own function for copying files. The task is to take each file and copy it to a directory. But it is copied like this: files are all in the right places, but the folders are all copied to the main category. Here is the structure of the original as it should be:

```
1c-win-x64 (Folder)
-----Dumps(Folder)
----------Files
-----Files

8.2.16.362 (Folder)
-----Files
```

Result after copying

```
1c-win-x64 (Folder)
-----Files

8.2.16.362 (Folder)
-----Files

Dumps(Folder)
-----Files
```

This is necessary in order to screw the ProgressBar in the future.

Help where is the mistake? Below function code

```
def copyTree():
    creat_folder = True
    total_size  = 0
    copy_size = 0
    src = path.realpath("1c82")
    destination = path.realpath("321321")
    for source, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for f in files:
            total_size += os.path.getsize(os.path.join(source, f)) ----- Sizing all folders
    for source, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for f in files:
            temp_folder = os.path.split(source) ------- Split last folder
            if not (os.path.exists(os.path.join(destination, temp_folder[-1]))):
                os.mkdir(os.path.join(destination, temp_folder[-1])) ------ Create folder
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, f), os.path.join(destination, temp_folder[-1])) ----- Copy file
copyTree()
```